# ImageField not uploading correctly

Tags: django, python-2.6, django-1.5, imagefield

I am trying to upload an image to the server. No matter what I do, it doesn't appear to properly upload the image. Here is my field in the model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/images/staff', verbose_name='Staff Member Photo', help_text='Required Dimensions: Square, about 275px height/width')
```

Here are my settings in the settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = 'static/media/'
```

I can't figure out what's going on--it's driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the absolute path in the `MEDIA_ROOT` property.  For example:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/mysite/static/media/'
```

BTW, what error you get then uploading the image?  Is it a path-related problem?

Comment: Where is "there"?  How do you upload the image? Show the view and template code, please.